# For loop not functioning correctly when assigned to a macro button?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologies for any mix ups in terminology as I've just started learning to use Google Apps Script. I recently created a Google Sheets spreadsheet report to help monitor accounts and log any issues with any of the client's devices ([click here to see said file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BWnHPwxMYgoTIP38MyoZAnGt7QwXnoR_G2oj-nJoiPY/edit?usp=sharing)). I've set up a "Start Report" button on the "Coversheet" sheet that is supposed to trigger the functions listed below;

```
function startReport()
{
  hideSheet();
  addXColumns();
};

function hideSheet() //Hides Coversheet from user's view.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
};

function addXColumns() //Adds columns based on the fleet size inputted by the user.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var fleetSize = sheet.getRange(3,3).getValue();

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();

  for (var i = 0; i < fleetSize; i++) //Performs steps through for loop until counter reaches fleetSize number based on user input.
  {
    spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertColumnsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastColumn(), 1);
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 1).activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#000000', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    spreadsheet.getRange('D6').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRange().autoFill(spreadsheet.getRange('D6:E6'), SpreadsheetApp.AutoFillSeries.DEFAULT_SERIES);
    spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
  }

  spreadsheet.getRange('E5').activate();
};
```

When executed, the "Report" sheet is supposed to have new columns inserted after column D based on the user input (fleet size) from "Coversheet". This script runs correctly when the active sheet selected in the UI is the "Report" sheet. However, every time I run the script in "Coversheet" the script runs through the functions but does not populate with new columns in the "Report" sheet. From what I can diagnose the error appears to be somewhere in this;

```
function hideSheet() //Hides Coversheet from user's view.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
};

function addXColumns() //Adds columns based on the fleet size inputted by the user.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var fleetSize = sheet.getRange(3,3).getValue();

  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Report'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('D:D').activate();
```

It seems like the sheet is not actively switching over from "Coversheet" to "Report" after the hideSheet() and addXColumns() functions execute. The variable fleetSize's value is C3 from "Coversheet", not C3 from "Report" (which is what I'm looking for).

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to run the function of `startReport()` at the sheet of `Coversheet` by pushing the button of "Start Report".
- In your shared Spreadsheet, the function name of the button of "Start Report" is `myFunction`. But you want to run the function of `startReport()`.
- You want to achieve this by modifying your script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the active sheet is used. So it fixes the sheet using `getSheetByName()`.

  - This is reflected to both `hideSheet()` and `addXColumns()`.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
function hideSheet() //Hides Coversheet from user's view.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A3:B5').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
};
```

To:

```
function hideSheet() //Hides Coversheet from user's view.
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Report");
  sheet.hideSheet();
};
```

And

From:

```
function addXColumns() //Adds columns based on the fleet size inputted by the user.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
```

To:

```
function addXColumns() //Adds columns based on the fleet size inputted by the user.
{
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Report");
```

#### Reference:

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSheetByName(String))

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Ontrak Solutions Support Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.